# Bluetooth hc-06 and Standalone Atmega168(possible?)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth

I am making a project that requires bluetooth communication between a Raspberry Pi(equipped with a bluetooth dongle) and a standalone atmega168 circuit.

I want to be able to transfer information serially between the two devices over bluetooth.

I have selected the hc-06 for the arduino and some usb bluetooth dongle for the PI.

I would like to know if connecting the hc-06's TX and RX pins to the RX and TX (respectively) pins of my atmega will work or not. If not, I would like to know how to achieve that (bluetooth on a standalone arduino-powered microcontroller)

Comment: Sound fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HC-0x Bluetooth transceivers are a drop-in replacement for a serial connection. Once the transceiver is configured (with baud-rate, device name, and pairing PIN #) you can plug it in in place of a serial line and expect to communicate. The device will take care of pairing and accepting a connection from the master device with no need for any code support from the AVR.

I use a separate program on an Arduino or a breadboarded AVR to configure my HC-06es. They retain their configuration across a power-down, and in fact, there is no hardware support for resetting them to a standard configuration; you need a program that figures out their current baud-rate in order to reconfigure them. It can save a bunch of hassle if you write down their configurations whenever you change them.

Comment: I have read somwewhere that a circuit for usb to serial is needed. I think that is for converting usb to serial(and back). Is it so ?

Comment: You'll need a USB to serial converter to connect your at mega to a computer through USB. But when you want to reprogram your atmega just use the arduino as ISP tutorial.

Comment: No circuitry is needed on the Arduino or AVR side; the HC-0x devices are directly pin-to-pin compatible, making them very convenient for standalone AVR devices. If you were thinking of the FTDI (or similar) serial to USB converters on Arduino boards, HC-0x devices don't need one.